# Html access files outside of the public folder

Tags: html, apache, security, directory

I have a php script called "upload.php" it has a couple of files that it needs to work. I don't want people to be able to access those files it needs by typing the filename in URL. What do  I do to make it possible for upload.php to access those outside of the public folder?

I guess it would be possible to put it all outside of the public folder and make a upload.html file to point to the upload.php? If yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you don't want people to access those files from outside the server then the best thing to do is to keep them outside of the public folder, elsewhere on the server's file system.  PHP, being interpreted server-side, will still be able to access the files (assuming the permissions are correct).

How you would access them depends on how "it needs to work" in your code.  Assuming for a moment that the files in question are PHP files which need to be included, [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) both take server-side paths and can reference any file on the server's file system.

Something like this:

```
include '/full/path/to/file.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put those php files in a folder, let's say "includes" and set a .htaccess file in it:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
```

Comment: I came across this with a similar requirement. I used your suggestion and the .php cannot not be requested directly, which is good. But unfortunately neither can my php include from another page on my site. The permissions are 644. Any ideas?

Comment: @square_eyes how are you including them ? If you're making an `http` request, then maybe you should also change the `allow from` part ?

Comment: I'm using `<?php include 'my/path/myfile.php' ; ?>`. Another thing to note is that some of the file seems to be included. I get a Div box, which is defined in the output of my .php file. Could it be the javascript that I also have in there that's failing? The file I'm including runs a small script that references two js libraries in the same folder.

Comment: In other words. My .php file that I'm including queries a database, writes out an array with javascript, then refers to a library ([Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/)) which renders a js chart. This ends up on the page that I have the include running. It all works until I set the .htaccess to lock down access to the standalone file.

Comment: @square_eyes it's getting quite complicated now, could you join the [PHP chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) ?